# MS Access Textbox Time control

Tags: ms-access, time

I am wondering if it is possible to control the time entered into MS Access textbox. Eg, only allow user to enter time in half hourly interval (08:30, 10:00, 13:30) as I do not want to end up with weird timing input.. (i.e 13:37, 16:42). Tried to use calculated control but doesn't seem to be working very well. Any suggestions or advice, please?

Calculated control in my textbox

```
=IIf((Minute([TxtStartTime1]) Mod 30=0),[TxtStartTime1],"00:00")
```

Below is a screen capture of my form.

[image: MS Access Txtbx Time Control]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, but it takes a little - actually that much, that I wrote an article on how-to:

[Entering 24-hour time with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23539/Entering-24-hour-time-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

It includes all the code needed to set the inputmask, validation, click and keypress events, as well as handling the form error - too much to post here.

Code is also on **GitHub**: [VBA.TimeEntry](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.TimeEntry.git)

To round the time, you may include this function:

```
Public Function RoundTime( _
    ByVal datDate As Date) _
    As Date

    Const cintMult As Integer = 24 '1 hour round
    ' Const cintMult As Integer = 48 '30 minute round
    ' Const cintMult As Integer = 96 '15 minute round
    ' Const cintMult As Integer = 144 '10 minute round
    ' Const cintMult As Integer = 288 '5 minute round

    RoundTime = CVDate(Int(datDate * cintMult + 0.5) / cintMult)

End Function
```

Comment: Brilliant! The code is indeed a bit long but it is a good tutorial to learn about the input mask and validation. Although in the end, I just used just part of it together with the RoundTime function in the On Exit event to get what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can round entered time for instance in BeforeUpdate event of your control. For rounding I use this VBA function:

```
Public Function TimeRoundMinutes(dtUnrounded As Date, Optional intRoundTo As Integer = 30, Optional intOption As Integer) As Date
'rounds time of provided date to specified in intRoundTo number of minutes. intOption:
'1 - down
'2 - up
'0 or anything else - to the nearest part
    Dim intMins As Integer

    If intRoundTo <= 0 Then
        intRoundTo = 1
    ElseIf intRoundTo > 60 Then
        intRoundTo = 60
    End If
    intMins = Minute(dtUnrounded)
    Select Case intOption
        Case 1
            intMins = Int(intMins / intRoundTo) * intRoundTo
        Case 2
            intMins = -Int(-intMins / intRoundTo) * intRoundTo
        Case Else
            intMins = Round(intMins / intRoundTo) * intRoundTo
    End Select

    If intMins = 60 Then
        TimeRoundMinutes = DateAdd("h", 1, Int(dtUnrounded) + TimeSerial(Hour(dtUnrounded), 0, 0))
    Else
        TimeRoundMinutes = Int(dtUnrounded) + TimeSerial(Hour(dtUnrounded), intMins, 0)
    End If
End Function
```